# Unable to start the hyperledger explorer locally. Throws 404

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

Starting the hyperledger explorer throws 404.

Here is what I have done:

Edited the config.json to point my locally running fabric network(deployed using composer sample network scripts).

Then started the explorer by ./start.sh

Check the logs in console,db,app. Nothing showing up

This is the what happening when I hit localhost:8080

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Port 8080 is where the composer playground usually is served from.

Once your network is up and running you can start the playground by issuing this command:

*composer-playground*

you run this from the folder where your network definition files are located.

If everything is done correctly it will start serving immediately on port 8080

Comment: I am looking to bring the explorer up not the composer.